# How to display images with large pixel values with matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib

matplotlib shows the white and black image, not the original image when I plot images of large pixel values.

Answer (score 0):

You get white pixels because values above 1 for `float` and above 255 for `int` get clipped.

You can normalize the values to avoid clipping:

```
# generate (100x100x3) array of random float64 values between 0 and 100
x = np.random.uniform(0, 100, [100, 100, 3])

# normalize
x_norm = x / x.max()

# plot original vs. normalized
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 2)
ax[0].imshow(x)
ax[0].set_title('original')
ax[1].imshow(x_norm)
ax[1].set_title('normalized')
```

Output:

[image: picture]

Answer (score 0):

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.image as mpimg
image = mpimg.imread("image.png")
plt.imshow(image)
plt.show()
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.

Comment: train_images, train_labels = next(iter(train_loader))
I iterate over the data loader, not use of imread